# Why is Yeoman not recommended for building websites?

Tags: yeoman

Why is Yeoman not recommended for building websites as they write on their website 
http://yeoman.io/road.html

> **Clearing up misconceptions**
>
> ```
> […]
> - Not recommended for building websites
> […]
> ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been answered on the [mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yeoman-dev/N4h71L9badQ):

> Yeoman is primarily targeted at improving the workflow for developers creating webapps. That's not to say that it can't be used to scaffold/build sites but we simply wanted to clarify that basic sites are not our target audience.