# Why does Yeoman require connecting to the internet when starting a new project?

Tags: security, gruntjs, npm, dependency-management, yeoman

Recently, I started using Yeoman to create static site projects built with Jekyll. `yo jekyllrb` runs fine but, in terms of security, I'm concerned about the part that comes after it prints:

`I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.`

If I'm not connected to the internet `bower install` still runs fine, but `npm install` gives the following error:

```
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch.git) fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch.git) github.com: Name or service not known
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/dannygarcia/grunt-jekyll.git) fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/dannygarcia/grunt-jekyll.git) github.com: Name or service not known
```

From what I understood by reading what is said [in response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938592/how-why-does-npm-recommend-not-running-as-root) about `sudo`, `npm`, and `chroot`, running an `npm install` potentially executes code from the internet and is therefore recommended to prefix such command with `sudo` in order to allow `npm` to downgrade privileges. Doing an `npm config set unsafe-perm=false` is supposed to force one to follow this recommendation. This, however does not have any effect on `npm install`, I guess, because it's a local install. This makes sense to me since (especially in a dev. env.) the code that is installed locally is most likely supposed to be executed by one's own user. What does not make sense to me is that, in the case of Yeoman, code has to be fetched from the web and executed with the same frequency that I start a new (simple) project, especially since `npm` does not check signatures. I imagine that a solution to this would be to disable `npm` for my user and copy the double-checked `node_modules` dir from another similar project. In the case of projects with more diverse needs, I would consider using a sandbox (perhaps with `chroot`).

What is the standard way of dealing with this issue? Does Yeoman provide any options that would allow one to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Bower is a little smarter about handling packages than npm, most times it will use a cached copy of a plugin so if you have jQuery version X installed in one project, and then use that same version in another, then Bower doesn't need to connect to the Internet in order to resolve that dependency, it will just pull from cache instead. That being said you still would have had to download that package in the first place in order to have that cached copy.

On the sudo thing, I've since learned that you shouldn't use sudo with package managers. Just going to quote from this answer here: ["sudo npm install -g grunt-cli" gives me an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736943/sudo-npm-install-g-grunt-cli-gives-me-an-error/)

> According to the maintainer of npm, installing packages with sudo is
>   considered bad practice because you are allowing that package to have
>   complete control of your system and you can't and SHOULDN'T trust
>   these packages with root access. Think Debian's long release cycles as
>   an extreme example of protecting end users from community maintained
>   packages for this exact reason.
>
> http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm
>
> You should do what Issaacs suggests and chown your /usr/local folder
>   so you have RW permissions.

So the issue you're having is that you don't want to run things with `sudo`. So don't. But if `npm install` throws an error it may be that you need to `chown -R /usr/local`, or another issue. In the case of node modules, they are installed *per project*, unless you install them globally with the `-g` flag, and even then you can have multiple projects with different versions of packages.

If you already have a project that uses Y version of `grunt`, `yeoman` etc, you might just want to copy over the relevant modules from another project. This will still work. However it's a lot simpler to do `npm install <package, ...> --save` or `--save-dev` to persist these dependencies in your `package.json` file, which makes cloning the project to another machine a lot easier (`git clone <project> && npm i`)

**TLDR**: *Both* Bower and npm install packages from the Internet, whether run under Yeoman or not; Bower is different in that sometimes it can make use of a cache.

Comment: Thanks. However, this is what the latest README says about sudo "As of version 0.3, it is recommended to run npm as root. This allows npm to change the user identifier to the nobody user prior to running any package build or test commands." https://github.com/isaacs/npm/tree/master . The issue I'm having is that npm tells me not to trust too much what I download with npm, but Yeoman wants me to trust what I download every time I start a new project (even the most simple one).Maybe this has to do wth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020529/why-is-yeoman-not-recommended-for-building-websites

Comment: I get that. If you're not comfortable using something that installs dependencies that you don't know about, you could try writing your own generator, OR vet the source of the generator you're using. Essentially a Yeoman generator just copies files into your project based on some variables you give it, which saves you having to copy manually from other projects. You can see the jekyll deps in this file: https://github.com/Thomas-Lebeau/generator-jekyll/blob/master/app/templates/_package.json & of course you could manually vet the generated `package.json` before doing `npm install`.